New version of Chrome broke chrome-php/chrome
I've been using HeadlessChromium in my PHP project on Ubuntu Server 23.10. Until recently, this worked to set up a new browser:
$browserFactory = new \HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory();
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser
(
    [
        'windowSize' => [1024, 768],
        'debugLogger' => 'php://stderr',
    ]
);

Today I upgraded Chrome to version 128.0.6613.84
The above code started giving this error:
PHP message: RuntimeException: Chrome process stopped before startup completed. Additional info: mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/.local': Permission denied
So I created /var/www/.local and set its owner to www-data. Now I get this error:
PHP message: RuntimeException: Chrome process stopped before startup completed. Additional info: chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
I've tried adding a few more options to no avail:
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser
(
    [
        'windowSize' => [1024, 768],
        'debugLogger' => 'php://stderr',
        'args' =>
        [
            '--no-crashpad',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless',
            '--disable-software-rasterizer',
            '--no-sandbox',
        ],
    ]
);

As far a I can tell the 'args' array has no effect.

The link to ~/.config/google-chrome may be wrong while there's also a bug filed: https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome/issues/610 ...does running eg. google-chrome-stable even work? This is probably more of a Chrome than a PHP problem.

@MartinZeitler google-chrome-stable doesn't work either. It is the same version as google-chrome. This is definitely a Chrome issue - I can replicate it by running sudo -u www-data google-chrome --headless

@MartinZeitler You were right about the .config directory. What worked for me was sudo mkdir ~www-data/.config ~www-data/.cache ~www-data/.pki && sudo chown www-data:www-data ~www-data/.config ~www-data/.cache ~www-data/.pki If you write up a solution I will accept it.

Opera 89 uses chrome_crashpad_handler.

Other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4.

Other ones as an app are in OS which it is for among others, and in U4. And in Sublime Text 3 build 4180.

The problem, as identified by @MartinZeitler is that there are directories missing from the www-data home directory. This solved the problem on my server (Ubuntu 23.10):
sudo mkdir ~www-data/.local ~www-data/.config ~www-data/.cache ~www-data/.pki && sudo chown www-data:www-data ~www-data/.local ~www-data/.config ~www-data/.cache ~www-data/.pki

In my case, the www-data home directory is /var/www

Mine issue was fixed by adding environment variables XDG_CONFIG_HOME and XDG_CACHE_HOME:
$browser = $browserFactory->createBrowser
(
    [
        'envVariables' => [
            'XDG_CONFIG_HOME'=>'/tmp/.chromium',
            'XDG_CACHE_HOME'=>'/tmp/.chromium',
        ]
    ]
);

